# How do I speed up a plotting of NIntegrate when repeated multiple times inside Plot?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I am studying a set of functions (many of which I know only as a definite integral) and I have assembled into a list.  Here is a sample:

```
Clear[functionsToPlot, totalFunctions]
functionsToPlot[x_] := {
  (*1*) NIntegrate[0.3/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.0 z + 0.7]/((z - 1)^2 + 1.1), {z, 0, x}],
  (*2*) NIntegrate[.03/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.5 z + 1.50 x]/((z - 1)^2 + .03), {z, 0, x}],
  (*3*) 0.5*Sqrt[x + 0.5]/x   
};
```

What I need is to make a plot of each curve *divided by the total*:

```
totalFunctions[x_] := Total[functionsToPlot[x]]

Plot[Evaluate[functionsToPlot[x]/totalFunctions[x]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

But the **problem** is that it takes forever.  I'm certain the `Plot` routine is doing the numerical integrals *twice* (once in the numerator, and again for the denominator).  Is there a way to teach *Mathematica* to form the total as it computes the various curves in the numerator as it produces the plot in realtime (or to make the task run more efficiently)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

Almost ten times faster again, or about 90 times faster than the OP's way (0.069 sec v. 5.46 sec):

For the second integral, we can find its derivative with respect to `x` and then integrate with `NDSolve`.  The derivative of the integral has two components, one from differentiating under the integral sign `dxdz1` and one from plugging in the limit of integration.  There is a coincidence here, that sometimes happens, namely, that the derivative with respect to `x` of the integrand can be integrated with respect to `z` relatively easily.

```
ad = Integrate[
   D[Rationalize[.03/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.5 z + 1.50 x]/((z - 1)^2 + .03)], x],
   z, Assumptions -> x > 0];

dzdx1 = ad /. {{z -> 0}, {z -> x}} // Differences // First // Simplify;

f2 = NDSolveValue[{
   f'[x] == 
     dzdx1 + (Rationalize[.03/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.5 z + 1.50 x]/((z - 1)^2 + .03)] /. z -> x), 
   f[0] == 0}, 
 f, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Replace `f2[x][x]` in `functionsToPlot` by `f2[x]` below in order to graph it.

**Original**

The first integral can be done once and for all with `NDSolve`.  The second can be set up with `ParametricNDSolve`, which will reuse the functions it computes (one for each `x`).  That will cut down on some time.

```
Clear[functionsToPlot, totalFunctions]
f1 = NDSolveValue[
    {f'[z] == 0.3/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.0 z + 0.7]/((z - 1)^2 + 1.1), 
    f[0] == 0}, f, {z, 0, 10}];
f2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    f'[z] == .03/(z + 2) Sqrt[z^2 + 2.5 z + 1.50 x]/((z - 1)^2 + .03), 
    f[0] == 0}, f, {z, 0, 10}, {x}];
functionsToPlot[x_] := {
   (*1*) f1[x],
   (*2*) f2[x][x],
   (*3*) 0.5*Sqrt[x + 0.5]/x};
```

It's about ten times faster this way (0.58 sec. vs 5.46 sec.).

Note:  One does have to pick an upper limit for `x` to use in `NDSolve`.  I picked `10`, but `3` is good enough for the example plot.

Comment: Nice.  I was struggling with the second term when you posted this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was struggling with too, until just before I posted it. :)  Thanks!

Comment: This is very nice!  That I have to pick an upper limit of `x` is no problem.   I also have two cases (in the list) where the upper limit of the integral looks like `(1-x)^2`.  Would that case also work with `NDSolveValue` or `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

Comment: @QuantumDot If I understand you right, you can use `NDSolveValue` if the only `x` in the integral is in the limits -- it can be any function such as `(1-x)^2`.  If `x` is in the integrand, too, then use `ParametricNDSolveValue` (unless the differentiate-integrate trick works).

Comment: Yes, I just now figured out how it works (I had never heard of `ParametricNDSolveValue` before now).  Thanks!